# How to use String in DirectCast in Visual Basic 2013?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, json.net, directcast

I was trying to DirectCast for Json, using the following code -

```
Dim EmailId as String
Dim URL as String
EmailId = txtEmailId.Text
URL = "http://localhost/json.php?id=" & EmailId

request = DirectCast(URL, HttpWebRequest)
response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
```

The problem is, the above mentioned method only works if I hard code Email id into URL. e.g `DirectCast("http://localhost/json.php?id=abcd@gmail.com", HttpWebRequest)`. When try to get Email id as variable I get following error -

> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to
>   'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'.

Please help me to make this work.

Comment: [`DirectCast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) is not a conversion tool from something to everything else.

Comment: If `DirectCast(URL, HttpWebRequest)` is not working, I highly doubt `DirectCast("http://localhost/json.php?id=abcd@gmail.com", HttpWebRequest)` is working.  You may want to double check that.

Comment: @roryap thanks for reminding me to double check. I forgot to add `WebRequest.Create(URL)` in `DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request = WebRequest.Create(URL)
```

Comment: I was about to post the same, that I forgot to add `WebRequest.Create(URL)` in `DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)`. Thanks.

Comment: I will, surely. I am waiting for stackoverflow time-limit of 5 min to finish :)